# Whenever I am running my VS HTML Code in chrome through go live, the html content is shown in some strange characters. What might be the problem?

Tags: html

I was just trying to run HTML Code on vs code through google chrome. Its working correctly on other browsers.

[image]

What can be the problem, the other html files are running correctly which I have made before.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you paste one html page content? The source code that you want to display?